# Bolt extension with extra dependencies in composer.json?

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm trying to create a local Bolt extension that uses extra libraries.  Here is a snippet of my `composer.json`:

```
    "type": "bolt-extension",
    "require": {
        "bolt/bolt": ">=2.0.0,<3.0.0",
        "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.7"
    }
```

**First**, is it even possible/advisable to manage dependencies this way in local Bolt extensions?  Or, do I need to manually include the library and autoload the files?

**Secondly**, what is the mechanism by which I should update the composer.json file in my extension?  Should I browse to the directory and run `composer update`, or is there a more Bolt-y way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, we disable the packagist repo in you `extensions/composer.json` by default — due to performance.

However, in the CLI, if you change to your extension's installed directory, a `composer update` will pull in/update the dependency for you.

All that doesn't mean this mightn't change, I am reworking the Composer code at present, so keep an eye on the changelog.

Comment: So, I moved to the extension's directory, and ran `composer update`, but I had to remover the dependency on Bolt in order for it to work.  It is using its own, isolated `vendor` directory for now, but I suppose that is fine to isolate the dependencies for the extension.